# Rotating a Label 90 degree in an Item Renderer

Tags: apache-flex, list, itemrenderer

I'm trying to rotate a label on my item renderer. 
When I rotate it 45 degrees, it's working just fine but when I rotate it 90 degrees, 
which is what I wanna do,  label is rotating but after list created, 
rotated labels are stepping up each other.

I can select the 45 degree ones but it seems like 90 degree ones has no
width at all. When I declare width and height and padding but that did not solve it too.

How can I make my labels 90 degree without making them step up each other?

My item renderer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" >
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            override public function set data(value:Object):void
            {
                super.data = value;
                dateLabel.text = data.date;

            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    /* When rotation is 90, my labels are just stepping up eachother */
    <s:Label id="dateLabel" rotation="45"/>
</s:ItemRenderer>
```

Comment: Does it happen precisely at 90 degrees? How about 80? 89? You may have to use absolute positioning if this is a flex bug.

Comment: It doesn't precisely happened at 90 degrees. It was like closer the degree to 90, smaller the renderer's width.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `BasicLayout` that your renderer is using (by default) doesn't respect the transformations that occur in the object's width/height/position/etc when you rotate it. It still tries to layout the objects as if they were not rotated.

However, if you use any other layout, like `VerticalLayout` or `HorizontalLayout`, the objects new dimensions (after rotation) are used.

I may not be explaining the above properly, but a simple solution to this problem is just to add a layout declaration to your renderer:

```
<s:layout>
    <s:VerticalLayout/>
</s:layout>
```